# regex version numbers from program version information

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to parse out two different sets of numbers in awk so I can compare them to the package version, to see if a upgrade needs to be completed or now.

Since the install file is labelled as `VMwareTools-8.6.11-1310128.tar.gz`

and the version checking application outputs

```
 vmware-toolbox-cmd -v
8.6.11.26309 (build-1310128)
```

I want to be able to parse out the 8.6.11 park, e.g. every beginning to the last period.  and then the - to the ), should be simple enough but I have been struggling with the regular expression. At least I think a regular expression is the best way to accomplish this.

I have this that strips out everything except for the numbers but that is not quite what I want.

```
echo "8.6.11.26309 (build-1310128)"|    sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
8611263091310128
```

Could you help by explaining how you figured out which regex to use?

Comment: If all you need is compare versions to check if you need to update or not, your way of removing everything but numbers do the trick already doesn't it? You can then do a simple comparison of `if(currentVersion < newVersion)` (since newer versions will always be higher in value) - Also, you can stop the comparison at the blank space so you skip the build number

Comment: But what if you had two of the same version numbers but only the build number was incremented.  That is why I wanted to be through and also compare using the build number.

Comment: Plus I was hoping to learn some more regrex, it is very complicated, but very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to get this,

```
$ echo "8.6.11.26309 (build-1310128)" | sed 's/^\(.*\)\..*\(-[^)]*\).*$/\1\2/g'
8.6.11-1310128
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Start of the line.
- `\(.*\)\.` Captures all characters upto the last dot character. But the dot character isn't captured.
- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times.
- `\(-[^)]*\)` - Upto the `-` symbol. Now  all the characters from `-` symbol upto the next `)` are captured and stored into another group.
- `.*$` - Matches remaining characters until the last.
- `\1\2` - Print only the captured characters.(ie, characters within first and second group)

Comment: Can you explain how you figured out the different parts.

Comment: @doanerock explained a bit :-)